# Overwrite javascript function at page load

Tags: javascript

There is a page, generated on server side with freemarker and java backend, which include a javascript.
This javascript create an object and call multiple method on it, one of them do an ajax call, all of this happening during page load.
I need to overwrite one function, which do the ajax call, on page load, but I can't modify the  server side, so I need to handle it somehow in the browser.
I know it's pretty easy if the method called on some event, button press for example, but how to achieve this during page load, after the object was created but before the method call?
Is it possible?

Example:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         var object = {
             init: function() {
                console.log('init');
             },

             ajaxCall: function() {
                 $.ajax('https://api.github.com/users/mongodb');
                 $.ajax('https://api.github.com/users/jekyll');
                 console.log('ajax');
             }
         }

         object.init();
         object.ajaxCall();
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hook your ajax requests with with jQuery's `ajaxSetup` or override the XMLHttpRequest class and have control over requests.

Comment: So, now he is suddenly using jQuery? cool

Comment: I need this for testing purpose and I can use jQuery.

Comment: @A1rPun can you give me some code example? I'm basically a Java developer, but sometimes my bosses want me to solve problems like this(with almost zero JS knowledge)...

Comment: @enapupe I mention jQuery because it alot easier to hook it. I just give possible solutions. I can create a fiddle for you birno.

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3djNp/) I demonstrate the use of the hook (check your console). You can check which request is send and execute your own code. It is very hacky but I hope this helps.

Comment: @A1rPun thanks, I see it works in fiddle, but how to inject this code? I uploaded the sample to dropbox: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6904740/index.html, how to do this without modifying the html on server?

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
theObject.theMethod = function() {
    // Code
};
```

Comment: Ok, I know this, but how to run the code after the object creation? If I run this before that, the script from the server will overwrite my method.

Comment: @birno Then just run it at [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/load) or [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded) events; or place the script just before closing `</body>`